# Unable to connect to RDS MySQL from Google App engine SQLAlchemy (unknown host error)

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, sqlalchemy, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect from my Flask app running on Google App Engine to a RDS database. My SQLAlchemy URI is

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql+mysqldb://<username>:<password>@******.cet1f6chsyad.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/<dbname>"
```

I get the following error:

```
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host '...' (2)")
```

If I attempt to connect to the database using Google Cloud Shell, I can connect properly. My command below works:

```
mysql -u <username> -p -h <url above>
```

Why is the Python code throwing an error?

Comment: FWIW, I changed the driver from mysqldb to pymysql and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

USE Sort CName instead of full RDS URL .

Sort Cname : `XYZ-RDSNAME.yourdomain.com`

instead of

```
  XYZ-RDSNAME.cet1f6chsyad.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com 

( ADD this entry into Route53 )
```

This is due to long URL , I have faced same issue some time while connecting mysql from terminal and bash script .